# Spring exceptions

Tags: java, spring, exception

Most of the exceptions thrown in spring are runtime exceptions which tend not be highlighted by eclipse (for me anyway). Is it just a case of learning what can be thrown and when or is there a better way of doing this. The reason i ask is because i find myself missing the catching of the run time exceptions and this obviously is not good.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most runtime exceptions are things you can't do anything about anyway, so your not catching them is mostly just as well. You should have an exception handler set up to catch all exceptions from the controller anyway, since you will want to log RuntimeExceptions regardless. There are some subclasses of DataAccessException (the one for handling violated unique constraints comes to mind) that you may need once in a while, but for the most part it shouldn't be an issue in practice.

TLDR version: I've been using Spring since 2004 and I know hardly any of the unchecked exceptions thrown by Spring. Don't worry about it, it'll be ok.

Answer (score 1):

Neither the compiler nor Eclipse will tell you about unchecked exceptions - because they're unchecked.    This is by design.

Look in the javadocs to see what can be thrown.

The real question is: why "obviously is not good"?  What do you do when you catch them?  Log and rethrow?  That's not handling.

You can catch DataAccessExceptions from the persistence tier and do something.  You can set up default pages for errors.  Lots of alternatives.